Generic bound on quadratic character sum
Let $\chi$ be the non-trivial quadratic character of $\mathbb{F}_q$, and let $f(x)$ be a square-free polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_q[x]$. Then by the Weil bound, we have the generic estimate $|\sum_{x\in\mathbb{F}_q}\chi(f(x))|\le \deg(f)q^{1/2}$. Say we now deal with a function $f(x,y)\in \mathbb{F}_q[x,y]$, so that we look for a bound on $|\sum_{x,y\in\mathbb{F}_q}\chi(f(x,y))|$. Do we have any similar generic bound, perhaps using the full power of the Weil conjectures? This is basically the number of points on the surface $z^2=f(x,y)$, but I don't know how to use the Weil conjectures to bound the number of points on this surface.
Edit: one could approach this by fixing $x$ and showing thay the resulting polynomial in $y$ is generically squarefree (or not a square). Thia gives a bound of order $q^{3/2}$ if works. I wonder if there's some tighter bound.

FWIW I have used the tag [tag:exponential-sums] for questions dealing with all character sums over finite fields. I understand that it feels a bit off when dealing with multiplicative characters, the quadratic character in particular. It just feels a bit awkward to introduce a tag covering all character sums, so... You are welcome to disagree, but I am even more uncomfortable using the tag [tag:characters] here. If for no reason other than its description explaining it to be used in the meaning familiar from representation theory.

Wow, you're fast. Seems fine to me :)

I'm afraid I don't know much about this. Weil bounds rely on us knowing the Betti numbers of the underlying projective varieties. Bounds of order $\mathcal{O}(q^{3/2})$ correspond to non-vanishing of a cohomology group (in the sense that if $H^3$ is non-trivial, we cannot expect better bounds in general). I vaguely recall having seen a few related vanishing results of such cohomology, but that's beyond my understanding to the extent that I cannot even suggest great buzzwords to search engines.

Thanks! Do you know of a reference for the relation to the vanishing of the third cohomology? Perhaps I will try to start from there.
